# Работа стрелочной функции, вызываемой array.reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я пишу функцию для проверки числа на Число Армстронга (такое число, которое равно сумме своих цифр, возведенных в степень, равную количеству его цифр).

Вот такая функция у меня вышла:

```
export function narcissistic(value: number): boolean {
    let sum: number = value.toString().split('').map(d => parseInt(d)).reduce((result, d) => result += d ** value.toString().length);
    return value === sum;
}
```

В некоторых ситуациях она отрабатывает верно. Но например с входным значением value=**8208** выражение вычисляется неверно, sum будет равно **4120**. Я так понимаю, что 8^4+2^4 =4112, а последняя 8 не возводится в степень.

Я пишу на TypeScript.

Буду благодарен за пояснение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> а последняя 8 не возводится в степень.

Не "последняя", а первая.

```
...reduce((result, d) => result + d ** value.toString().length, 0);
                                                              ^^^
```

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> If initialValue is not specified, previousValue is initialized to the
> first value in the array, and currentValue is initialized to the
> second value in the array.

---

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let sum = value.toString()
    .split('')
    .map(d => parseInt(d))
    .reduce((result, d) => result + d ** value.toString().length, 0);
  return value === sum;
}

console.log(narcissistic(8208));
```